# How to create a function that can mutate variables in loop in R

Tags: r

I am working with a dataset that includes both frequencies and percentages for different demographic variables. I want to create a loop that is able to change both the frequency and percent to NA if the frequency is less than five. Basically, the brute force way I have so far is:

```
df <- df %>%
mutate(
# Suppressing N's
n_lep = ifelse(n_lep < 5, NA, n_lep),
n_eco = ifelse(n_eco < 5, NA, n_eco),
n_fem = ifelse(n_fem < 5, NA, n_fem),


# Suppressing P's
p_lep = ifelse(n_lep < 5, NA, p_lep),
p_eco = ifelse(n_eco < 5, NA, p_eco),
p_fem = ifelse(n_fem < 5, NA, p_fem)
)
```

There are more variables than the 3 above, which is why I'd like to figure out a way to do this through a function and/or loop if possible. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the across function inside mutate to apply the same function to multiple columns

Comment: you just need to use the `<<-` global assignment operator

Comment: @ivan866, mind posting an answer using your suggestion, I'm curious what this means in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do that in base:

```
data(iris)
df <- iris
names(df)
#> "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species" 

vars <- c("Sepal", "Petal")
fields <- c("Length", "Width")

for(v in vars){
  for(f in fields){
    df[,paste0(v, ".", f, "_new")] <- ifelse(df[,paste0(v, ".", f)] < 1, NA, df[,paste0(v, ".", f)])
  }
}
head(df)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Length_new
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa              5.1
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa              4.9
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa              4.7
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa              4.6
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa              5.0
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa              5.4
#>   Sepal.Width_new Petal.Length_new Petal.Width_new
#> 1             3.5              1.4              NA
#> 2             3.0              1.4              NA
#> 3             3.2              1.3              NA
#> 4             3.1              1.5              NA
#> 5             3.6              1.4              NA
#> 6             3.9              1.7              NA
Created on 2021-09-22 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

In your case, you'd use `vars <- c("n", "p")` and `fields <- c("lep", "eco", "fem")` and replace the `.` with `_` in each `paste0()`.

Or as a function, if columns numbers 1 through 4 contain the values you'd like to manipulate:

```
sapply(df[,1:4], function(x) ifelse(x<5, "NA", x))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried that and I get the following error
```
Error: Can't recycle input of size 26 to size 1.
```
I thought this might be due to the NA, so I tried this:
```
for(v in vars){
  for(f in fields){
    df[,paste0(v, "_", f)] <- ifelse(df[,paste0(v, "_", f)] < 5, df[,paste0(v, "_", f)] == NA, df[,paste0(v, "_", f)])
  }
}
```
But I still got the same error. Any suggestions?

Comment: You're welcome! I can help troubleshoot this if you can please share sample data in your question.

Comment: I updated my answer with example data.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Were you able to figure it out on your side?